# Saving a file relative to working directory

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, fileoutputstream

I'm writing a program that downloads a file from an ftp, I want the files to be placed in a folder called "files" in the working directory, but I'm not sure how to change my output stream to do this.

Here is my code:

```
String remoteFile1 = f.getName();
System.out.println(remoteFile1);
File downloadFile1 = new File(fileName);
OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
boolean success = client.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
outputStream1.close();
if (success) {
    System.out.println(fileName + " has been downloaded successfully.");
}
```

I'm not sure which part I need to edit to change the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to change your `fileName` to include the directory name ("files"), for example (thanks to @MadProgrammer):

```
File downloadFile1 = new File("files/", fileName); // Modify this line
```

Also, if the directory does not exist, please add the following code at the beginning:

```
new File("files").mkdirs();
```

Comment: Or `File("files", fileName)`, which can sometimes be more useful ;)

Comment: I did try that, but I get the error java.io.FileNotFoundException: files/Tul1D_diGly-K_r1.raw (No such file or directory)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Cool, thanks for this elegant solution!

Comment: @user2320239 Did you create the directory `files`?

Comment: Yes, the files directory exists. Would there be a way to make the program create  the folder if it does not already exist?

Comment: @user2320239 Yes, please try `new File("files").mkdirs();`

Comment: @user2320239 Thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96611/discussion-between-tsung-ting-kuo-and-user2320239).